# How to find the PostgreSQL installation folder via Java without user interaction?

Tags: java, postgresql, processbuilder, pg-dump

In my Java application I want to implement the option to dump/restore a PostgreSQL database. Some google research showed me that calling pg_dump/pg_restore via Java's ProcessBuilder is probably the best way to achieve this.

Now I'd like to determine the system's directory of pg_dump.exe/pg_restore.exe *without* asking the user to specify it manually. How can I find the PostgreSQL installation path through Java?

Thanks in advance and
all the best,

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that portably.  I suggest that you just call the programs without path by default and rely on the user having set an appropriate path, and have a way for the user to configure the paths explicitly.  You can also look in some likely directories for a default configuration.  But it will be quite fragile in general, especially if you want to cover all of Windows, Linux, and Mac, say.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to simply define an environment variable called `PG_HOME` and use `System.getEnv("PG_HOME");` to retrieve that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look inside the default directories first (probably somewhere `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\...`). Use different combinations to be as tolerable as possible.
2. If it fails, just search the file system. Nice example [here](http://vafer.org/blog/20071112204524/).
3. Also see [How to do a backup from a Postgresql-DB via JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810288)

Comment: Please don't search the file system.  It could be a big file system.