# PostgreSQL save database data

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans

im working in a netbeans project and i need to save the data from a postgreSQL every day, so i can send it to a secure folder in the network.

Is there anyway to do that, save the data or the entire database (Script + Data).

Software: Netbeans JDK 6 , postgreSQL 9.4

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: There is no api to do that ??  I need to exec a command ?

Comment: How is Netbeans specific to your question? What is the task? Do you want to backup your database during your development within Netbeans or do you want to backup your application database in your java application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a backup from a Postgresql-DB via JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810288/how-to-do-a-backup-from-a-postgresql-db-via-jdbc)

Comment: Nice solution too, i think both solutions can work. I will pick the one that fits thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look into a scheduled backup for your db, and version control for your code

Comment: Big thanks that´s what i needed. Didn´t know that PostgreSQL can make schedule backups.

Comment: @epicUT It is not PostgreSQL, but your OS which provides some kind of scheduler, e.g. cron (Linux) or task scheduler (Windows).